# Rotate axis labels in jqplot

Tags: jqplot

I'm trying to replicate the rotated labels example at http://www.jqplot.com/tests/rotated-tick-labels.php using:

```
axesDefaults: {
    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
    tickOptions: {
      angle: -30,
      fontSize: '11pt'
    }
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XV5yz/2/

But I can't get the rotated labels... I think I've included all the relevant js files...

The "fontSize" option works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jqplot files aren't correct. Try to include those instead :

- http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqplot/1.0.8/jquery.jqplot.js
- http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqplot/1.0.8/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js
- http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqplot/1.0.8/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js
- http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqplot/1.0.8/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js
- http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqplot/1.0.8/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js

You need to increase div height too in order to see ticks well fitted :

```
<div id="chart2" style="height:400px;width:300px"></div>
```

Please see working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/XV5yz/5/)